# Stop form element from disrupting formatting of inner elements

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a table made out of `div` elements, with the rows of this table generated from a for loop using a Jinja2 variable. The problem is that I need the entire table row to be included in the `form` element, however doing so disrupts the formatting and breaks the table headers from the table rows. How can I achieve what I'm attempting below, without disrupting the formatting?

All row cells need to be included in the looping form, as I'm using these cells as user inputs.

```css
div.blueTable {
  border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableCell, .divTable.blueTable .divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 3px 2px;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableBody .divTableCell {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableRow:nth-child(even) {
  background: #D0E4F5;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableHeading {
  background: #1C6EA4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableHeading .divTableHead {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableHeading .divTableHead:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.blueTable .tableFootStyle {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.blueTable .tableFootStyle .links {
  text-align: right;
}
.blueTable .tableFootStyle .links a{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #1C6EA4;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.blueTable.outerTableFooter {
  border-top: none;
}
.blueTable.outerTableFooter .tableFootStyle {
  padding: 3px 5px; 
}
/* DivTable.com */
.divTable{ display: table; }
.divTableRow { display: table-row; }
.divTableHeading { display: table-header-group;}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead { display: table-cell;}
.divTableHeading { display: table-header-group;}
.divTableFoot { display: table-footer-group;}
.divTableBody { display: table-row-group;}
```

```html
<div class="divTable blueTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
      <div class="divTableRow">
          <div class="divTableHead">head1</div>
          <div class="divTableHead">head2</div>
          <div class="divTableHead">head3</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableBody">
      <form method="POST"> <!-- For loop starts here -->
      <div class="divTableRow">
          <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="jinja variable used for id">
          <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" value="someValue"></div>
          <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" value="anotherValue"></div>
          <div class="divTableCell"><button>Submit</button></div>
      </div>
      </form> <!-- For loop ends here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tired this:

```
<form method="post" class="divTableRow">
   <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="jinja variable used for id">
   <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" value="someValue"></div>
   <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" value="anotherValue"></div>
   <div class="divTableCell"><button>Submit</button></div>
</form> <!-- For loop ends here -->
```